# Alfresco audit web interface

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco generates an audit trail logging events such as "User A logged in" or "User B deleted document X".

This audit log is visible from command line or via a REST API.

But is there a web application that would show this audit data?

The data should be sortable by date, user, action, document.
The data should be paged so that browsing is smooth even when there is a huge quantity of audit data in Alfresco.

Bonus if the interface is only viewable by Alfresco administrators.

Must work on a local network (not SaaS).
Preferably free, ideally open source.

Comment: Did you look at [Alfresco Audit Analysis and Reporting (A.A.A.R.)](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-audit-analysis-and-reporting-aaar)? I've not used it myself, so I can't recommend it either way, but I've heard a few people mention good things about it at Alfresco meetups over beer...

Comment: @Gagravarr: Nice to see you here! I love Francesco's work, feel free to post an answer about AAAR. Please mention all of the pieces that need to be installed for the audit web interface to work (ex: Pentaho?), and whether audit events can be seen in near real-time. Thanks :-)